# 7z command line and GUI password inconsistencies

Tags: 7-zip

I'm seeing some weird behavior with 7z.  I create an archive with the following command:

`7za.exe a "zip_test.zip" -r "C:\zip_test\*" -p"abc123"`

When I open the archive `zip_test.zip` using the 7z GUI and attempt to extract a file I'm asked for a password as expected, but when I run the following command on the same archive all the files and directories at the top level are extracted without me having provided a password, and I'm only prompted for a password once 7z starts processing deeper levels (i.e. not the top level), after the top level files have already been extracted:

`7za.exe x -y -o"C:\zip_test" "C:\zip_test.zip"`

I know the zip format has limitations when it comes to password protection, but I would expect 7z GUI and 7z command line to behave the same on the same archive.  I do not see this behavior when using the 7z format.

Some clarification of what is going on here would be appreciated.

Comment: Anecdotally, doing a bit of experimenting on Windows 7, `7za.exe` (7zip 9.20 command line) apparently behaves slightly differently than `7z.exe` (7zip 19.00) in terms of the files/placeholders (with `7za.exe`, not all the placeholders(?) are apparently always 0B when the wrong password is entered). Even so, and even using `7za.exe`, with the wrong password, none of the "extracted" non-0B files seem usable. I think the (partial) solution here is to upgrade 7zip (though you still not may have "no files" as with the GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, and there might be some detail you have missed.

The files are not extracted, and only zero-size place-holders files are created,
waiting for the password to be entered.

If the password is not entered, or an erroneous password is used,
the files will stay as zero-size.

Sub-folders cannot be password protected, so are created without the need for the
password.

Comment: The missing detail was that the file unzipped by 7z command line was zero sized and had no content.  I didn't open the file originally to see that it had no content.  7z command line and 7z GUI just don't behave the same in this manner which was confusing me.  Thanks!